# Eyeball loop select?

Tags: modeling

Blender Noob here. I am following alongside this tutorial and I am stuck. At the 4:40 mark he selects the front most vertex of the eyeball and then says he presses "Ctrl+" to make the face step selection. Ctrl+ however is just zooming me in like it should? Am I hearing him wrong in the video?
Thanks!

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tCuMiE91p-I&list=PL32001WLw6WG8glAk8LpFO1dbDbBGE8bI&index=3

Comment: He is referring to Ctrl numberpad +. Its the shortcut for "Select More".If you hit the space bar to open the Search tool and type in Select More you will see the the keyboard shortcut. also in the video at 4:40 In the Last Operator panel (bottom left below the Tools panel, you will see that is the tool he has just used to select the edge loop.

Comment: @3fing It'd be nice if you could post that as a proper answer, maybe even with information on how to change it in the user prefs and what to do if one doesn't have a numpad.

Comment: @Leander, Unfortunately its my bedtime.

Comment: @3fing Well anytime the next days would do.